# Hot to split geom_col by different groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to split the graph below by countries. It shows the share of education comparing 2000 with 2020. But i would like to see this comparison by countries, first germany 2000 compared with germany 2020 next to each other, then the same for the United Kingdom next to them. My guess is that i have to do it with `position = "dodge"`, but i am not sure where to include it.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=share, x=country,fill= education)) + 
  geom_col(aes(time))
```

[image]

Here is the data:

```
  df=  structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Germany", "United Kingdom"
    ), class = "factor"), education = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("High", "Mid", "Low"
    ), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2000", "2020"), class = "factor"), 
        share = c(33.2845576041362, 56.9310311189152, 46.4851806022038, 
        41.3352189028342, 49.8323036187114, 38.9338040600176, 39.9891518069022, 
        48.1659773543969, 47.2698138789597, 38.9375077036854, 44.5437053326003, 
        43.9618838189481)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `position` outside the `aes` in `geom_col`.  By default, the value is `"stack"`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y=share, x=country,fill= education)) + 
   geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
   facet_wrap(~ time)
```

Comment: It does not work, this code splits the education categories next to each other and the countries do not show next to each others

Comment: @Jad Your x specified in `ggplot` aes is country and you changed that to time.  I was not sure why you changed it

Comment: @Jad I removed the second `aes` and added the `facet_wrap` with `time`

Comment: I am sorry to bother again, but what if i want the same graph you suggested, but instead of having the level of education next to each other, i want them in one column stacked for each country. How can i do that?

Comment: @Jad Just remove the `position = "dodge"` I guess

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, fill = education, y = share)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use `facet_wrap()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y=share, x=country,fill= education)) + 
    geom_col(aes(time), position = "dodge") +
 facet_wrap(~country)
```

the untidy way is to map `country` to `colour` aesthetic (it's not):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y=share, fill= education, colour = country)) + 
    geom_col(aes(time), position = "dodge")
```